# Json Object with 2 nested objects of same type

Tags: java, json

I have a very simple question which doesnt seem to have an answer.

I have an object which has 2 objects with same type inside it and they are not arrays. How do i represent it in json?

```
GroupOfEmployees{

Employee emp1;
Employee emp2;
}

Employee{
String name;
int id;
}
```

emp1 details:
name:first
id: 1

emp2 details:
name: second
id:2

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for the json object which represents GroupOfEmployees object then the sample json will be something like below

```
{
    "emp1": {
        "name": "name1",
        "id": 1
    },
    "emp2": {
        "name": "name2",
        "id": 2
    }
}
```

**update**
when you convert above json into object, you will get an object which holds two employee objects with name emp1 & emp2. Consider the following example

The following is your Employee Class:

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;

    private int id;

    public Employee(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    // getter & setter methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Employee [name=");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append(", id=");
        builder.append(id);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

The following is GroupOfEmployees class:

```
public class GroupOfEmployees {
    private Employee emp1;
    private Employee emp2;

    // getters & setters method

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("GroupOfEmployees [emp1=");
        builder.append(emp1);
        builder.append(", emp2=");
        builder.append(emp2);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

here goes main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee emp1 = new Employee("name1", 1);
    Employee emp2 = new Employee("name2", 2);

    GroupOfEmployees groupOfEmployees = new GroupOfEmployees();
    groupOfEmployees.setEmp1(emp1);
    groupOfEmployees.setEmp2(emp2);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    String jsonValue = gson.toJson(groupOfEmployees);
    System.out.println("jsonValue = " + jsonValue);

    GroupOfEmployees newGroup = gson.fromJson(jsonValue, GroupOfEmployees.class);
    System.out.println("Object value = " + newGroup);
}
```

and finally output is :

```
jsonValue = {"emp1":{"name":"name1","id":1},"emp2":{"name":"name2","id":2}}
Object value = GroupOfEmployees [emp1=Employee [name=name1, id=1], emp2=Employee [name=name2, id=2]]
```

Comment: Actually I want to make a json which can be reconverted to the mentioned objects later using gson library. So in this solution it will  convert this json to an array of employee objects with 2 elements, which I want to avoid. I want them to be converted to 2 separate objects exactly as shown in the question . How to achieve that?

Comment: +1 coz u understood the question correctly.Can you explain how is the toString method getting called?

Answer (score 1):

Make a `JSONArray`:

```
[
{
name: "name1",
id: = id1 }, 
{
name: "name2",
id: = id2 }
]
```